# How do you to configure a hotkey in Lynx browser to open page the system browser?

Tags: mutt, lynx

When you're viewing an HTML page in Lynx, sometimes text-only formatting isn't adequate (especially for poorly designed HTML). Can Lynx be configured to open the current page in another browser (e.g. firefox) with a hotkey?

I'm trying to accomplish the following progression for viewing html emails:

mutt > lynx > firefox

I can open html emails in lynx with the following setup in my .muttrc:

```
# .muttrc
auto_view text/html                                      # view html automatically
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html     # save html for last
```

And this setup in my .mailcap file

```
# .mailcap
text/html; w3m -I %{charset} -T text/html; copiousoutput;
```

[Reference](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2012/05/12/mutt/)

However, once I'm viewing a message in lynx, I'd like the option to set a shortcut key to open a full-featured browser (i.e. firefox) in case the message requires some more advanced rendering.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out based on this [StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42712/open-html-attachments-externally-in-mutt).

#### .muttrc file

```
# .muttrc
auto_view text/html                                      # view html automatically
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html     # save html for last
```

#### .mailcap file

```
# .mailcap
text/html; firefox '%s' &; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"; needsterminal;
text/html; lynx -dump %s; nametemplate=%s.html; copiousoutput;
```

Comment: There are some big e-mail platforms (Sendgrid) that will auto-convert even `text/plain` attachment into `text/html`.

It has become a necessity to `alternative_order text/html text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Keystroke Commands](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/keystrokes/keystroke_help.html) that will run an external program on the link:

> `.` Run external program on the current link.
>
> `,` Run external program on the current document.